# having 2 ui-tabs active color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm trying to have different color when the ui-tabs is active, i'm using jquery ui but can't manage to do that.
any help ?

here is the jsfiddle files !
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/7TwyM/1/)

HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs_main_1">main1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs_main_2">main2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs_main_1">
        <div id="tabs_child_1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#child_sub1-1">sub1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#child_sub1-2">sub1-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#child_sub1-3">sub1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="child_sub1-1"></div>
            <div id="child_sub1-2"></div>
            <div id="child_sub1-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs_main_2">
        <div id="tabs_child_2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#child_sub2-1">sub2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#child_sub2-2">sub2-2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="child_sub2-1"></div>
            <div id="child_sub2-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap_ui_tabs { width: 980px; min-height: 100px; padding-top: 36px; color: #000;}
.ui-tabs { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav { padding: 10px 30px 30px 0px; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { background-color: #dddddd; list-style: none; float: left; position: relative; top: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; padding: 0; white-space: nowrap; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav a { color: #fff; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor { float: left; padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { background-color: #41b2f2; color: #fff; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active .ui-tabs-anchor,.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled .ui-tabs-anchor,.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-loading .ui-tabs-anchor { cursor: pointer; }
.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active .ui-tabs-anchor { cursor: pointer; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { display: block; border-width: 0; background: none; }
```

Comment: do you want to change the blue color from active, is that it?

Comment: dont put the js in the html section of jsfiddle.  I updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/7TwyM/1/).  not sure of the problem though. when i click a tab it and its parent are both blue.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your fiddle. It's working fine for me.

Comment: i want to have 2 active color like blue and red, like when i'm on "main2" the active color is red and when i'm on "main1" the active color is blue..